# WSL hide /mnt/c/Users/

Tags: windows, git, ubuntu, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

It is possible to view shorter path in my terminal (VS Code & Hyper) with WSL (Ubuntu). On top of the Ubuntu, I have installed zsh. Currently, I am using a git bash and path looks `Lukas@Y50-70 ~/Coding` but with the Ubuntu, I have something like this `lukas@Y50-70 /mnt/c/Users/Lukas/Coding`. When I have a project in another 2 folders or so and I have a long branch name it is annoying to have a full row unnecessary info (for me).
Here is a comparison of Ubuntu and git bash: 
[image: comparison of Ubuntu and git bash]
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve this using Named Directories - by adding this line to your ~/.zshrc file

```
hash -d c=/mnt/c
```

you will see '~c/' in your prompt rather than '/mnt/c/' which I think is a lot nicer.

This has a similar effect to setting an alias for the directory but the name is reflected in how your path is displayed.

As an added bonus you can then switch to that directory at any time by typing `~c`

Answer (score 2):

Check if the [zsh installation guide under WSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/795#issuecomment-254078271) can help (from [neurogenesis](https://github.com/neurogenesis)):

> 1. Install `zsh` with `sudo apt-get install zsh`
> 2. `bash.exe` is the entrypoint to the WSL / linux subsystem. You'll have to modify the windows shortcut to specify `bash -c --login` or modify `~/.bashrc` with `exec /bin/zsh` to properly load a different shell.
>      `/etc/passwd` isn't consulted because it's not a full login process. Be sure to set your `SHELL` env var as well. See [#846](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/846) for details.
> 3. Fix your `umask` before you start installing things, otherwise tools like zsh will complain.
>      Specifically, "`group`" and "`other`" permissions will have the same privileges that owner do. This causes zsh's `compaudit` and `compinit` to fail (both are related to command completion).
>      See [#352](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/352) for details. `umask 022` can be added to your `~/.bashrc`.
>
> NOTE: This should be done before trying to install `zsh` plugin managers like `antigen` (otherwise the directory/file permissions issues from git clones).
>   You should also do this before installing RVM or rbenv.
>
> I ended up inserting a few lines to the top of my `~/.bashrc`, something like the following:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

## Fix missing umask value
umask 022

## Launch Zsh
if [ -t 1 ]; then
  cd $HOME
  export SHELL=/bin/zsh
  exec -cl $SHELL
fi
```

---

[Issue 846](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/846) (mentioned in point 2) includes [the comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/846#issuecomment-242909925):

> A normal `-c zsh` symlink opened up in the wrong directory to me, but I managed using this (note the tilde):

```
C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe ~ -c /bin/zsh
```

---

See also "[How to Use Zsh (or Another Shell) in Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/258518/how-to-use-zsh-or-another-shell-in-windows-10/)".

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question, but maybe I'm reading it differently from how you are. I think the question is about `PS1` including the complete current directory path.

Comment: @hvd Exactly: I hope with those settings, $HOME will be recognized as ~.

Comment: But the default `$HOME` isn't `/mnt/c/Users/...`. The OP isn't in a subdirectory of `$HOME`.

Comment: That is a bad idea, because `/mnt/c/...` doesn't have POSIX semantics. This can break programs which store certain types of files in `$HOME`.

Comment: @hvd Agreed. I'll wait for the OP's feedback to know more.

Comment: for now, I leave it like it is now, maybe I will try to "fix" it later because I don't want to break something. but thanks for answers

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't exactly the fix you were hoping for. I was looking to solve the same issue. The prompt was just too long and it was causing some of my commands to wrap to the next line. After seeing the comments on VonC's answer, I'm deciding to keep my next-best solution.

What I did in my ~/.bashrc file is this:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\n\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\n\$ '
fi
```

I added a `\n` right before the `\$`

So when I'm at my Windows home folder, it looks like this

```
ryan@DESKTOP-RSKAA4F:/mnt/c/Users/ryank
$
```

And I start typing my commands after the `$`. It takes up more vertical space, but at least I don't have to maximize my terminal window just to avoid text wrap.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that just running 'cd' after starting the terminal session, re-bases the prompt to the normal '/home/(user)'

there should be no need for installing zsh or anything else. It works for me anyway.

also when starting the session at the root folder from windows, seems to do the trick.

I keep my sessions under

C:\vms

sample:

```
cd -d C:\vms\minikube\ubu_jenkinsX\rootfs
C:\vms\minikube\ubu_jenkinsX\rootfs>wsl -d ubu_jenkinsX
```

Yours may be under your userprofile in local data. Search for the rootfs folder

Answer (score 0):

The reason your WSL prompt shows such a long path is because you're not actually in your home directory. You see, WSL has its own virtual filesystem separate from Windows, and Windows paths (like your `C:\Users\Lukas\...`) are stored under `/mnt/c/Users/Lukas/...`. Your WSL home directory would be `/home/Lukas` (since your WSL username is capitalized), but of course, that's not where your project is.

The `fish` shell has a [`prompt_pwd`](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/prompt_pwd.html) function that shortens a path to something like this:

```
0 ---- /m/c/U/L/Documents cd Something
0 ---- /m/c/U/L/D/Something prompt_pwd
/m/c/U/L/D/Something
```

Is that something you're interested in? You could port [the function](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/bcbfd70d413155152ce1261f925a62b678c83d32/share/functions/prompt_pwd.fish) to Bash, or just switch to Fish, or just display the current directory name instead of path.